# Replace Activity's fragment with another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

My application has a Fragment inside its Activity. I would like to programmatically replace the fragment by another one from the current fragment itself.

For example, if I click on a button inside the fragment, the fragment should be replaced with another one, but the activity should remain the same.

I tried this code but it says that fragment_container "cannot be resolved to a symbol" What is fragment_container?:

```
 // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new GPAFragment2Test();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

EDIT: Here's the code that sets up the tabs:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragment for 1
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            //Fragment for 2
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            //Fragment for 3
            return new Fragment3();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3; //No of Tabs
}
```

Comment: fragment_container is the parent layout where your fragment resides. (ie. a framelayout / linearlayout / relativelayout ...)

Comment: @rupps I managed to get it to work, but now the old fragment is still on top of the new one. How do I completely get the old fragment to disappear?

Comment: @rupps I'm doing this within a tab btw.

Comment: Is the fragment you're replacing added in the XML? If so, unfortunately you can't remove it. You can only replace (remove) fragments you've added programmatically

Comment: @rupps Well the fragment I'm replacing inflates an XML layout that presents the buttons,textviews, and so forth. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @rupps Nope! What do I do from here?

Comment: How are you adding the first `Fragment`?

Comment: Is your tab system working ok? when you click the tabs, do the fragments change?

Comment: uff.. that's not the way to replace a fragment that comes from an adapter. I'd make the adapter return this new fragment, then call notifyDataSetChanged(). By replacing it "hard-core"you are interferring with the FragmentAdapter's own logic to add/replace fragments.